# IE7 and IE8 - why don't they remember select box values?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a super simple form, with a select drop down box.  All browsers remember the selection, except IE8 and IE7 (IE9 works).  I am doing a post.  the doctype is HTML.  What else do I need to add?

print_R($_POST) shows the values correctly in all browsers including IE9 - except IE 7 and IE8

```
<form method='POST' action='/someaction'>
    Timezone : 
    <select name='user_time_zone' id='user_time_zone'>
        <option value='UTC'>UTC/GMT</option>
        more options here
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Set' style='padding-left: 5px; height: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px;'>
</form>
```

Comment: Remember when ? using the back button ? or revisiting the page ?

Comment: when I submit the form, and print the POST variable, it doesn't contain the correct value

Comment: post your PHP and HTML code...

Comment: @user187809 The problem is with the browser if the server side code doesnt contain the correct value for a posted form. The problem is something else - please post all of your server side code thats relavent

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is not with your browser, but rather with your code. Using http://browserstack.com, I was able to fire up a quick vm of Windows XP and test both IE7 and IE8. Further, I tested IE10 on my local machine - all browsers [showed the posted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbnx7.png) as expected.

```php
<?php

    if (count($_POST)) var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

```html
<form method='post'>
    <label for="user_time_zome">Timezone:</label> 
    <select name='user_time_zone' id='user_time_zone'>
        <option value='foo'>Foo</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Set'>
</form>
```

Sample Output:

```
array
  'user_time_zone' => string 'foo' (length=3)
```